# speeding up applying a function to unique values in R

Tags: r, performance, data.table, lapply

I was hoping somebody could help, I'm trying to speed up an apply function, and I've tried a few tricks but it is still quite slow and I was wondering if anybody had any more suggestions.

I have data as follows:

```
myData= data.frame(ident=c(3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,7,7,7,7,7,7,7),
group=c(7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8),
significant=c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0),
year=c(2003,2002,2001,2008,2010,2007,2007,2008,2006,2012,2008,
2012,2006,2001,2014,2012,2004,2007),
month=c(1,1,9,12,3,2,4,3,9,5,12,8,11,3,1,6,3,1),
subReport=c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
prevReport=c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

and I want to end up with a dataframe like this:

```
results=data.frame(ident=c(3,4,7),
significant=c(1,0,1),
prevReports=c(2,6,7),
subReport=c(0,1,0),
group=c(7,7,8))
```

To do this I wrote the code below and to do it quickly i've tried converting to data tables and using rbindlist instead of rbind, which I've found suggested in a few threads. I've also tried parLapply, I still find the process to be quite slow however, (I'm tring to do this on about 250,000 data points).

```
dt<-data.table(myData)

results<-NULL

ApplyModel <- function (id,data) {

dtTemp<-dt[dt$ident== id,] 

if(nrow(dtTemp)>=1){

prevReport = if(sum(dtTemp$prevReport)>=1) sum(dtTemp$prevReport) else 0 

subsequentReport =  if(sum(dtTemp$subReport)>=1) 1 else 0 

significant = as.numeric(head(dtTemp$sig,1))

group = head(dtTemp$group,1)

id= as.numeric(head(dtTemp$id,1))

output<-cbind(id, significant ,prevReport,subsequentReport ,group)

output<-output[!duplicated(output[,1]),]
print(output)
results <- rbindlist(list(as.list(output)))

 }
}


results<-lapply(unique(dt$ident), ApplyModel)
results<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, results))
```

Any suggestions on how this might be speeded up would be most welcome! I think it may be to do with the subsetting, I want to apply the function to a subset based on a unique value but I think lapply is really more for applying a function to each value, so subsetting is defeating the object somewhat...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, your code produces an error:

> results<-lapply(unique(dt$ident), ApplyModel)
>       Error in dt$ident : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

It appears to me, that you are looking for tapply instead of lapply. Using tapply you could express roughly the above in much more concise ways:

```
results2 <- data.frame(significant = tapply(myData$significant, myData$ident, function(x) return(x[1])),
                       prevreports = tapply(myData$prevReport, myData$ident, sum),
                       subReports = tapply(myData$subReport, myData$ident, function(x) as.numeric(any(x==1))),
                       group = tapply(myData$group, myData$ident, function(x) return(x[1])))
```

Should do about the same job but be much more readable. Now this should really be fast except for huge datasets. In most cases it should be faster to wait for R to complete the job than to spend more time programming. One way to make this even faster would be to use the power of the data.table package, but just invoking it doesn't do the trick. You'll need to learn it's very special syntax. Please check before, that the code given this way really is too slow.
If it is really too slow, check this:

```
library(data.table)

first <- function(x) x[1]
myAny <- function(x) as.numeric(any(x==1))
myData <- data.table(myData)

myData[, .(significant=first(significant),
           prevReports=sum(prevReport),
           subReports=myAny(subReport), 
           group=first(group)), ident]
```

Comment: Creating `first` seems like overkill; `myAny` should coerce to integer instead of float; and the correct way to transform to a data.table is `setDT(mydata)` (without any `<-` assignment).Finally, the syntax needed for this example is not very special; you're just making it harder than necessary to read by omitting whitespace and passing `by=ident` by position rather than name. These aren't big problems; just letting you know. Also, regarding learning the syntax, you could link to the vignettes: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints and for pointing me to setDT(). Whether to define first and whether to state argument names and where to set spaces is a matter of taste. I think, that myAny probably should not coerced at all as booleans probably reflect the values best. 

To the matter of the syntax of data.tables: We will probably agree, that data.table has it's own DSL that is compact, to-the-point and useful. The original poster appears to struggle with basic R and I advise novices to learn basic R first, before diving into DSLs within R like data-table, ggplot2, regular expressions.

Comment: continued: That again is a matter of taste but I believe, that learning data.table should come after one has learned basis-R like tapply, aggregate, doBy and the likes. 
That being said, linking to the vignettes is a great addition.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)

new <- myData %>% group_by(ident) %>% 
summarise(first(significant),sum(prevReport),(n_distinct(subReport)-1), first(group)) %>%
data.frame()
```

Comment: `max(significant)` will lead to incorrect results if zero is first and 1 is second. Better to use `dplyr::first`

Comment: @ Piere Lafortune Still works if 0 is the first element of the grouped variable. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Edit the data with `myData[4,3] <- 1` and check the answer. Your syntax will lead to the incorrect result of `1` for the `ident` `4`. The correct result is `0` as per the OP's condition.